# Zoom in zoom out on touch devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

I try to do with zoom in zoom out on touch devices (like phone, tablets...)

```js
function resizeImg(img) {
  var resize = 150; 
  var origH = 61;  
  var origW = 250; 
  var mouseX = event.x;
  var mouseY = event.y;
  var newH = origH * (resize / 100);
  var newW = origW * (resize / 100);

  // Set the new width and height
  img.style.height = newH;
  img.style.width = newW;

  var c = img.parentNode;

  // Work out the new center
  c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
  c.scrollTop = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
 <img alt="Click to zoom" onclick="resizeImg(this)"
     src="http://www.logiticks.com/wp-content/themes/logiticksv4-theme/images/2015/12/datatable.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Firstly, I'm sorry for my limited knowledge about this problem.
But how can I zoom in/zoom out the img when I run the app on touch devices? I mean, how can we pinch gestures to zooom in/out but it still in the div tag (not zoom in/out all the page/browser)? :D

Someone have the experienced about zooming, could you please give me an idea for this? I truly thankful ^^

Addition: This is my resizeImg function. But it still doesn't work on touch devices and reaaly hard to use :(

Comment: `resizeImg()` add this also

Comment: @Durga: I've added my resizeImg() function on my post. Can you take a look for this? Thank you ^^